# How do I remove input placeholder text on focus with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="testimonial-form__field testimonial-form__company-name">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap company-name">
        <input type="text" name="company-name">
    </span>
    ::after
</div>
```

I'm having trouble writing a jQuery snippet to remove/hide the ::after pseudo element when the input comes in focus. Specifically traversing the DOM up and out of the input.

```
$('.testimonial-form__field input').css( "display", "none" );
```

That is about the extent of my JS knowledge. I know I need to start by selecting the input and end by applying a hide on the pseudo element. I just don't know how to write that function.

Comment: pseudo element `::after` is likely generated from css, you should look into CSS, not jQuery

Comment: I've tried that. To my knowledge there is no way to use the ::focus state on the input and traverse up and out of the DOM with CSS because parent selectors don't exist.

Comment: You could listen for the *"focus"* event on the input, traverse up to the parent and toggle a class that corresponds to some CSS like `.someClass:after { content: none; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest on input focus you simply add a class to the .testimonial-form__company-name div element. When that happens, you just add a CSS class to hide the ::after psuedo element.

Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/c5a19byk/

```
<style>
  .testimonial-form__company-name::after {
    content: "not focused";
    display: block;
  }
  .testimonial-form__company-name.active::after {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<div class="testimonial-form__field testimonial-form__company-name">
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap company-name">
     Input: <input type="text" name="company-name">
   </span>
</div>

<script>
  $('.testimonial-form__company-name input').focus(function () {
    $(this).closest('.testimonial-form__company-name').addClass('active');
  }).blur(function () {
    $(this).closest('.testimonial-form__company-name').removeClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks